# I meet this error when I trying to add a MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I had tried to update the NuGet package of the CodeGeneration to the newest version but it still gives me this error.

Do you guys have any idea about it?

Here is the error message is shown:

[error_message_show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxMHK.png)

Comment: What does your appsettings.json `"ConnectionStrings":` have for you database connection?

Comment: `"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-GMIBODO;Database=Bulky;Trusted_connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
  }`, ya it is connected to my local database.